# JS is saying that I have an undefined object. Could REALL use some help figuring this out

Tags: javascript, json, google-api

Today I was tasked with working with the Google API for the first time to create a map. I had no problem setting up the map on my site, and that was easy enough. But for some reason my points I coded with json are not showing up. It is saying that my  gmap object is undefined. I could really use some help here, I've been starring at this thing ALL DAY!!

```
function load () {
    var map = document.getElementById("map");
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var gmap = new GMap2(map);
        gmap.addControl( new GSmallMapControl() );
        gmap.addControl( new GMapTypeControl()) ;
        gmap.addControl( new GOverviewMapControl(new GSize(100,100)) );
        gmap.setCenter( new GLatLng(42.3313889, -83.0458333), 7 );
    } else {
        alert("Sorry, your browser cannot handle the true power of Google Maps");
    }
}

window.onload = load;
window.onunload = GUnload;

function createMarker(input) {
    var marker = new GMarker(input.point);
    GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        marker.openInfoWindowHtml( input.walkName + input.date + input.address );
    });
    return marker;
}

function parseJson (doc) {
    var jsonData = eval("(" + doc + ")");
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.markers.length; i++) {
        var marker = createMarker(jsonData.markers[i]);
        gmap.addOverlay(marker);
        }
}

GDownloadUrl("points.json", function(data, responseCode) {
    parseJson(data);
});
```

Comment: Is there an element on the page with the id of map?

Comment: Yes, the map displays fine. The problem here is the markers aren't showing up with the addOverlay function in the paarseJson function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `gmap` is defined within the scope of the `load` function. So it's not available in the `parseJSON` function where you reference it.

Comment: So, I should define it in the parseJSON function as well? Would I just copy that same line and put it in there?

Comment: No. Put `var gmap;` at the top of your code and change the line `var gmap = new GMap2(map);` to `gmap = new GMap2(map);` (remove the word `var`). This defines the variable `gmap` in the outer scope so both `load` and `parseJSON` can 'see' it. Currently it's declared inside the `load` function, so `parseJSON` can't 'see' it.

Comment: Okay I did that, and the points still aren't showing. Its saying, Cannot call method 'addOverlay' of undefined.

Comment: Is `load` being executed _before_ `parseJSON`? `load` initializes the map, you can't draw anything if you don't have the map yet :P

Comment: I believe so, I mean can't you see it in my code from above? I put the load function first.

Comment: Yes, you put it first, but is it being executed first? `load` is executed on `window.load`. `parseJSON` is executed when the call to `"points.json"` returns, that might happen before!

Comment: So I should move window.load to the top then?

Comment: Moving the code isn't going to change anything, you need to change the timing, for instance move the `GDownloadUrl etc..` part into the `load` function so it always loads _after_.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the gmap variable inside your parseJson function. But it is declared inside the load() function. They don't share scope. Just move the gmap declaration outside of both functions so it is in a common scope to both of them.

Comment: Hi, I tried that but once I took both out their functions the map wouldn't load. I know the one in the load function has to stay there because of it is what allows the map to display in the div tag with the id map in my html.